# Crystal Reports - a way to change a field from one type to another?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, report-designer

I need to change a large number of running total fields to formulas based on those running totals.  They already have custom formatting and suppression applied.  Is there anyway to switch the source/type of the field from the running total to the formula so I don't have to manually re-apply all the complex formatting and suppression rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of writing an app to copy the object formatting across to new objects (leaving you to create/delete objects as required, as the Crystal API for dotNET is much more limited than the Reporter Designer API for VB was)...I do not believe any way of doing this exists.

The Format Painter menu option will make copying all the formatting between a Running Total field object and a corresponding new Formula-based object less of a pain, though.